# Как обратиться к элементу списка Python

Tags: python, массивы

Есть список: a = [1,2,3,4,5]
Я ввожу порядковый номер элемента с клавиатуры: c= int(input("Vvedi nomer "))
потом запускаю цикл : for i, ii  in enumerate(a):
как обратиться к любому из элементу списка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно что вы сами ответили на свой вопрос:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i, ii in enumerate(a):
    print(a[i])

c = int(input("Введите номер:"))
try:
    print(a[c])
except Exception as exc:
    print(str(exc))
```

Comment: в вашем примере `a[i] is ii`—можно напрямую `ii` (придумав возможно лучше имя) использовать, вместо обращения по индексу. Можно просто: `print(exc)` вместо `print(str(exc))`.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за уточнения, все так.